# Why is Python try and except not suppressing error?

Tags: python

Why am I still throwing a Traceback. I am trying to make sure that the user enters a numeric value instead of a string. I thought my try and except would catch and clear the surpress.

Here is the program output including traceback.

```
# python conversion.py 
Select conversion type, 1) inches to mm 2) mm to inches     -1
Invalid response. 

Select conversion type, 1) inches to mm 2) mm to inches     g
Invalid response. 

Select conversion type, 1) inches to mm 2) mm to inches     1

Please specify inches in decimal to convert to mm   1
1.0 inches is equal to 25.4 mm
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mcolombo/conversion.py", line 67, in <module>
    select_conversion()
  File "/home/mcolombo/conversion.py", line 58, in select_conversion
    select_conversion()
  File "/home/mcolombo/conversion.py", line 56, in select_conversion
    if conversion_type < 1:
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Here is the code snip where the error is being thrown.

```
 48 def select_conversion():
 49       conversion_type=input("Select conversion type, 1) inches to mm 2) mm to inches \t")
 50       try:  # checks if input is numeric
 51          conversion_type = int(conversion_type)
 52       except:
 53          print("Invalid response. \n")
 54          pass
 55          select_conversion()
 56       if conversion_type < 1:
 57          print("Invalid response. \n")
 58          select_conversion()
 59       elif int(conversion_type) > 2:
 60          print("Invalid response. \n")
 61          select_conversion()
 62       elif int(conversion_type) == 1:
 63          in_mm()
 64       else:
 65          mm_in()
 66
```

I was expecting the except block to suppress the traceback and not show after the program finishes running.

Comment: Also, it's very bad form to use a bare `except:`; in real-world code, you should _always_ catch only specific errors you know how to handle, and let new/different/unexpected errors bubble up.

Comment: Don't use recursion to implement an open-ended (possibly infinite) loop.

Comment: There's no reason to convert the responses to integers in the first place. They're essentially just labels: use string comparisons to figure out which option was entered. (Do you really care to support, for example, hexadecimal input for a menu option?)

Comment: `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'` is the real error.

Comment: There's nothing "after the program finishes running" about it, either. Your program just isn't finished when you think it is, because you didn't think about what happens when the recursive calls return. It's not truly _finished_ until the stack is unwound.

Comment: Think about logic of your code: an exeption happens. You call `select_conversion` again recursively. Then that call finishes... and happens what? Which line is executed next and what value of conversion_type would it use if `int(conversion_type)` failed?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy do you have any suggestion for the type of exception I should us?

Comment: @fukanchik Thank you. I added a quit() to the end of mm_in() and mm_in(). I no longer get the traceback when testing with a string instead of a numeric value.

Comment: @korbdallas, the only kind of exception `int(somestring)` is expected to throw is `ValueError`, so that's the appropriate type in this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, try block is correcly suppressing the execption from `int()` conversion. However, when it fails, `conversion_type` still stays as value entered by user. Most likely it is a string. Then error is actually thrown in the `if` statement. Something like that is happening there:

```py
# note that "banana" is a string, not variable
if "banana" < 3:
 print("Small banana")
```

And it stays in each recusive function call you make, it is not discarded when you make another call to the funciton.

So eventually, when user enters correct value, that function call executes properly. But after that, it goes to the previous funciton call, where the values is incorrect, and tries to process it as if it is an integer value, which throws an exeption.

In my opinion, you should create separate function for getting value from the user, and only use it in your other functions. Here is my version of such function, as I don't know your requirements, I keept it recursive, although I wouldn't do it like that:

```py
def get_user_input():
    user_input = input("Select conversion type, 1) inches to mm 2) mm to inches \t")
    try:
        user_input = int(user_input)
    except:
        print("Invalid response. \n")
        user_input = get_user_input()
    return user_input
```

You can make is as versatile as you want. Here an example function accepting type from user and message:

```py
def get_user_input(message, var_type=int):
    user_input = input(message)
    try:
        user_input = var_type(user_input)
    except:
        print("Invalid response. \n")
        user_input = get_user_input(message, var_type)
    return user_input

print(get_user_input("Enter a numer please: "))

# Enter a numer please: t
# Invalid response. 
#
# Enter a numer please: j
# Invalid response. 
#
# Enter a numer please: 10
# 10
```

I hope I helped you!

Comment: Thank you all There are so many great responses here. I learned a lot of great techniques for handling this input. I currently worked around the issue by adding a quit() statement to the end of mm_in() and in_mm(), but I plan on going back and using some of the other examples shared here in order to make my code simpler and easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs because after the recursive call to `select_conversion` returns, you *continue* with the current call, where `conversion_type` was never successfully converted to an integer. You shouldn't use recursion to implement a loop, and you don't actually need to convert the input to an integer in the first place. (You aren't, for example, trying to do arithmetic with the input; just treat it as the label that it is.)

Eliminating both sources of the error gives you a much simpler function.

```
def select_conversion():
    while True:
        conversion_type = input("Select conversion type, 1) inches to mm 2) mm to inches \t")
        if conversion_type == "1":
            return in_mm()
        elif conversion_type == "2":
            return mm_in()
        else:
            print("Invalid response")
```